# What can I use as replacement for $pager_total_items?

Tags: 8, search

I updated a website to Drupal 8.9.6. I saw that the global `$pager_total_items` was used, but it is deprecated since Drupal 8.8.0.

Ia m looking for an alternative to retrieve the total items of the pager.
This was used on a **Search API page**.

The old code is the following one.

```php
$variables['count_results'] = empty($GLOBALS['pager_total_items']) ? 0 : $GLOBALS['pager_total_items'][0];
```

After reading [The pager has now a backend changeable service](https://www.drupal.org/node/2779457), I tried to use the following code.

```php
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Pager\PagerManager $pagerManager */
$pagerManager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager');
$pager = $pagerManager->getPager());
```

It seems the  Search API module, and `$pager` does not contain the expected pager object.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
$pager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager')->getPager();
$count_results = $pager->getTotalItems();
```